# Google Maps Android API v2 - DirectionsRenderer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I already searched on StackOverflow and Google. But i didn't find a real answer. I think there is just no DirectionsRenderer in the Android API. But can you acknowledge this?

If there is not DirectionsRenderer, how could i use the Android API to show a GoogleMaps and draw a Route on the Map?

I want to draw a nice route. Not just lines between the coordinates of each route-section which are also delivered from the Directions-Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i found out that it is possible to just take the legs, then the steps and within the steps you will find the "points".. when you decode the points string its a very detailed list of all coordinates.

with this coordinates, you can easily draw a nice route on the map.

so it's possible without the need of a additional Web-API.

Answer (score 2):

> I think there is just no DirectionsRenderer in the Android API. But can you acknowledge this?

There is no `DirectionsRenderer` in Maps V2. You can tell this by reading [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

> how could i use the Android API to show a GoogleMaps and draw a Route on the Map?

There is nothing in Maps V2 to support this.

> I want to draw a nice route. Not just lines between the coordinates of each route-section which are also delivered from the Directions-Request.

You will need to find some Web service that will serve up coordinate information for the route with sufficient granularity (e.g., every 10m) to give you your "nice route", then use a `Polyline` or something like that for actually rendering the route.